# XPath trying to get the third position

Tags: xpath

I want to get the authors on the third position. I am using //authors[3]. Is there any reason this way does not work? When i type //authors[1] i get the whole row.

```
<publications>

    <publication>

    <publication_name> Group agency: The possibility, design, and status of corporate agents </publication_name>
    <authors> C List,P Pettit  </authors>       
    <publisher> Oxford University Press </publisher>
    <year> 2011 </year>
    <citation> 598 </citation>

</publication>

<publication>

    <publication_name> Aggregating sets of judgments: An impossibility result</publication_name>
    <authors> C List, P Pettit  </authors>      
    <publisher> Economics and Philosophy </publisher>
    <volume> 18 </volume>
    <number> 1 </number>
    <pages> 89- 110 </pages>
    <citation> 558 </citation>
    <year> 2002 </year>e

</publication>

<publication>

    <publication_name> Epistemic democracy: generalizing the Condorcet jury theorem</publication_name>
    <authors> C List, RE Goodin  </authors>     
    <publisher> Journal of Political Philosophy </publisher>
    <volume> 9 </volume>
    <number> 3 </number>
    <pages> 277-306 </pages>
    <citation> 409 </citation>
    <year> 2001 </year>

</publication>

<publication>

    <publication_name> Arrow’s theorem in judgment aggregation </publication_name>
    <authors> F Dietrich, C List  </authors>        
    <publisher> Social Choice and Welfare </publisher>
    <volume> 29 </volume>
    <number> 1 </number>
    <pages> 19 - 33 </pages>
    <citation> 220 </citation>
    <year> 2007 </year>

</publication>

<publication>

    <publication_name> Deliberation, single-peakedness, and the possibility of meaningful democracy: evidence from deliberative polls </publication_name>
    <authors> C List, RC Luskin, JS Fishkin, I McLean  </authors>       
    <publisher> Journal of Politics </publisher>
    <volume> 75 </volume>
    <number> 01 </number>
    <pages> 80-95 </pages>
    <citation> 143 </citation>
    <year> 2013 </year>

</publication>


<publication>

    <publication_name> Swarm intelligence: When uncertainty meets conflict </publication_name>
    <authors> L Conradt, C List, TJ Roper </authors>        
    <publisher> The American Naturalist </publisher>
    <volume> 182 </volume> 
    <number> 5 </number>
    <pages> 592-610 </pages>
    <citation> 10 </citation>
    <year> 2013 </year>

</publication>

<publication> 

    <publication_name> Intradimensional Single-peakedness and the Multidimensional Arrow Problem </publication_name>
    <authors> C List </authors>
    <publisher> Theory and Decision </publisher>
    <citation> 10 </citation>
    <year> 2004 </year>

</publication>

<publication>

    <publication_name> The methodology of political theory </publication_name>
    <authors> C List, L Valentini  </authors>       
    <publisher> The Oxford Handbook of Philosophical Methodology </publisher>
    <citation> 8 </citation>
    <year> 2016 </year>

</publication>

<publication> 

    <publication_name> Social choice theory and deliberative democracy: a response to Aldred </publication_name>
    <authors> JS Dryzek, C List </authors>      
    <publisher> British Journal of Political Science </publisher>
    <volume> 34 </volume>
    <number> 4 </number>
    <pages> 752-758 </pages>
    <citation> 8 </citation>
    <year> 2004 </year>

</publication>

<publication>

    <publication_name> Episteme symposium on group agency: Replies to Gaus, Cariani, Sylvan, and Briggs </publication_name>
    <authors> C List, P Pettit </authors>       
    <publisher> Episteme </publisher>
    <volume> 9 </volume>
    <number> 3 </number>
    <pages> 293 </pages>
    <citation> 5 </citation>
    <year> 2012 </year>

</publication>

<publication> 

    <publication_name> Two intuitions about free will: Alternative possibilities and intentional endorsement </publication_name>
    <authors> C List, W Rabinowicz  </authors>      
    <publication> Philosophical Perspectives </publication>
    <volume> 28 </volume>
    <number> 1 </number>
    <pages> 155-172 </pages>
    <citation> 4 </citation>
    <year> 2014 </year>

</publication>

<publication>

    <publication_name> Reasons for (prior) belief in Bayesian epistemology </publication_name>
    <authors> F Dietrich, C List  </authors>        
    <publisher> Synthese </publisher>
    <volume> 190 </volume>
    <number> 5 </number>
    <pages> 787-808 </pages>
    <citation> 4 </citation>
    <year> 2013 </year>

</publication>

<publication> 

    <publication_name> Freedom as independence </publication_name>
    <authors> C List, L Valentini  </authors>       
    <publisher> Ethics </publisher>
    <volume> 126 </volume> 
    <number> 4 </number>
    <pages> 1043-1074 </pages>
    <citation> 3 </citation>
    <year> 2016 </year>

</publication>

<publication>

    <publication_name> Belief revision generalized: A joint characterization of Bayes' and Jeffrey's rules </publication_name>
    <authors> F Dietrich, C List, R Bradley </authors>      
    <publisher> Journal of Economic Theory </publisher>
    <volume> 162</volume>
    <pages> 352–371 </pages>
    <citation> 3 </citation>
    <year> 2016 </year>

</publication>



    <publication>

        <publication_name>Which worlds are possible? A judgment aggregation problem</publication_name>
        <authors>C List</authors>
        <publisher>Journal of Philosophical Logic</publisher>
        <volume>37</volume>
        <number>1</number> 
        <pages>57-65</pages>
        <citation>12</citation> 
        <year>2008</year>

    </publication>





</publications>
```

I only want to get the author on the third position.

There is no result and i get an error saying: The XPath query returned no results. XPath scope:current file.

Answer (score 1):

For Xpath 1.0 you can use next expression

```
//authors[substring-after(substring-after( . ,',' ),',')]
 /substring-before(concat(normalize-space(substring-after(substring-after(.,',' ),',')),","),",")
```

The 1st part of Xpath selects `authors` tag having not less that 2 comma.

If you want to get the name of the third author not using a programming language, the second part will do that.

I've splitted the Xpath for readability

Comment: That took an impressive amount of work to eliminate the XPath 2.0 `tokenize()` function.   I confirmed that this selects the same as the [**XPath 2.0 expression I wrote**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47660863/290085).  Unfortunately, it **still requires XPath 2.0** because it uses a function (`substring-before()`) as the last step of a location path; this powerful construct isn't available in XPath 1.0.   I'm still upvoting, though, to try to offset the pain and suffering you obviously endured to get this close.  :-)

Comment: @kjhughes https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring-before ?

Comment: `substring-before()` itself is fine; it's its position at the end of the step path that requires XPath 2.0.

Comment: Yes, I understood

Answer (score 0):

This **XPath 2.0** expression,

```
//authors[count(tokenize(.,',')) > 2]/tokenize(.,',')[3]
```

will select the third author listed for each publication,

```
JS Fishkin
TJ Roper
R Bradley
```

for those `author` elements that have 3 or more authors (as identified via comma separation).

XPath 1.0 solution is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said, note that `//authors[1]` selects every `authors` element that is the first `authors` child of its parent, while `(//authors)[1]` selects the first `authors` element in the entire document, which is I think what you want.

(You talked of getting the "whole row". I have no idea what a "row" is in an XML context. If you want to communicate clearly, the first rule is to learn the technical vocabulary...)

Comment: I meant that instead of getting only the third author on the third position i was getting the whole row with all of the authors of the publication. I hope that you understand what i meant.

Comment: No, I have no idea what you mean by "row".

Answer (score 0):

You can select third author with this xpath

```
//authors[contains(text(),' C List, RE Goodin ')]
```